# Passing UTF-8 string to f:viewParam in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, character-encoding, mojibake, viewparams

I tried to pass UTF-8 String as `f:viewParam` value but value shown as garbage string, i added EncodingFilter in `web.xml` for setting UTF-8 to request and response as below

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

and i defined facelet page in this style, but problem not resolved

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="q" value="#{searchBean.query}"/>
</f:metadata>
.....
</html>
```

I test this with Myfaces 2.0.5 and Mojarra 2.0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you're using a server configuration which interprets GET query strings using a different character encoding by default. For example Tomcat interprets them as ISO-8859-1 by default. You need to open Tomcat's `/conf/server.xml` and add `URIEncoding` attribute to the [`<Connector>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) element with a value of `UTF-8`.

```xml
<Connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8">
```

That filter is by the way totally unnecessary. Remove it. JSF 2.x on Facelets defaults to UTF-8 at all levels already. Besides, the `HttpServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding()` doesn't affect GET requests, it affects POST requests only.

#### See also:

- [Tomcat HTTP connector configuration reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)
- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)